# Trigger click on non-hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-io, onclick

So I am trying to do the standard "have a button trigger a file input field" thing.  However, I haven't even gotten to hiding the input field yet - right now it is visible on the page along with the button that should trigger the click.  However, it is not working.

```
<body>
    <button id="uploadDocument" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        <span>Check In</span>
    </button>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" />
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#uploadDocument").on("click", function() {
            $("#fileupload").trigger("click");
       });
    });
</script>
```

For whatever reason, this doesn't work.  Like I said, and as you can see, the input field is not hidden - it's right there on the page.  Nothing happens at all.  If you debug it and put breakpoints in the code, it never gets hit.  I figure it's gotta be something obvious, but I've racked my brain and I can't figure it out.

Comment: $("#fileupload").click()

Comment: Your code works fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epfk5ya6/). However, if you change the version of jQuery to a older one, it won't work. Older versions of jQuery don't trigger the browser events. Is your jQuery up to date?

Comment: We're using jQuery 1.11.0 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Style-Guide

**Why isn't it possible to programmatically trigger the file input selection?**

Most browsers prevent submitting files when the input field didn't receive a direct click (or keyboard) event as a security precaution. Some browsers (e.g. Google Chrome) simply prevent the click event, while e.g. Internet Explorer doesn't submit any files that have been selected by a programmatically triggered file input field.
Firefox 4 (and later) is so far the only browser with full support for invoking "click"-Events on a completely hidden (display: none) file input field.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I missed that part of the jQueryUpload documentation - so janky that that is how we have to do it, but it makes sense with the security risks otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

you should trigger onchange not click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uploadDocument").on("click", function() {
        $("#fileupload").trigger("change");
   });
});
```

check here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/af6oe6wr/)